# How do you derive the formula for converting weight percent to atom percent?

Tags: materials, mathematics, material-science

I have the following equations for weight and atom percent:

[image]

Where m is the mass of each element.

[image]

[image]

where A is the atomic weight of each element and m prime is the mass of each element.

And I'm told that you can convert between them with the following equations:
[image]

My question is how are the two sets of conversion equations derived?

Comment: Take the conversion for atom percent to weight percent, C1 for example, substitute all the C primes for their equivalents from the definition of atom percent, and then simplify the equation. You'll see it's a matter of manipulating the units by rearranging and substituting n = m/A in the different definitions.